# Anchor contains no text

Tags: html

```
<a href="#sidewidgetarea" aria-label="Navigation Menu" aria-expanded="false" class="closed"> <span a ...
```

Repair: Add text to the a element or the title attribute of the a element or, if an image is used within the anchor, add Alt text to the image.

what i need to do ?

Comment: `<a href="#sidewidgetarea" aria-label="Navigation Menu" aria-expanded="false" class="closed"><span>My Text</span></a>`. The span isn't necessary, but since it's a part of the example, I kept it. As for images, they have an `alt` attribute to set the alt text: `<img src="path/to/image" alt="my alt text" />`.

Comment: the issue here is that i got no img on this part of the code. thats why i am so confused and cant do it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put an Alt text to an img you can do this

```
<img src="path" alt="your text">
```

Comment: the issue here is that i got no img on this part of the code. thats why i am so confused and cant do it

Answer (score 0):

1. "*Add text to the a element or the title attribute of the a element*"

Here, means to add text inside `<a>` tag and to add `title` attribute to it. Titles are given to elements when you want to describe something. When you add **title** attribute, if you hover over the element, a pop up will be shown.

```html
<a href="https://Google.com" title="If you click on this, it will direct you to google">
        Google[hover]
</a>
```

2. "*if an image is used within the anchor, add Alt text to the image.*"

Well, this means you must use a `<img/>` tag inside a `<a>` tag. And to add **alt** attribute to the image. Alt is good for SEO and highly recommended. When the image, for some reason, doesn't show, here *alt* comes for help and describes your image.

```html
<img src="URL" alt="The image is not loaded, because I didn't add a source" />

<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="You won't see alt now, because image will be shown" />
```

P.S. **Here is a website that provides random image: [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/)**.

Comment: here it is the hole code. I put title and still nothing

<div> <a href="#sidewidgetarea" title="SideWidget" aria-label="<?php echo esc_attr__('Navigation Menu', 'salient'); ?>" aria-expanded="false" class="closed"> <span aria-hidden="true"> <i class="lines-button x2"> <i class="lines"></i> </i> </span>SideWidget</a> </div>